# Expression Lambda - retriveing Filed

Tags: linq, entity-framework, c#-4.0

is it possibile executing through Expression class a Select (projection) passing data field as string in order to achieve a strongly typed collection?

That' because I'm working with Linq to Entities and I would be able to making some retrive by grabbing wpf grid column name.

IS it exist something like Expression.Lamba.Select("field1, field2") which return a List..?

Comment: You should do it the other way around, creating column names from entity properties.

Comment: Have a look at some of the techniques Rob Conery uses in his [Massive project](http://blog.wekeroad.com/helpy-stuff/and-i-shall-call-it-massive)

Answer (score 1):

You could create a method that would call `Select()` with an expression that creates a `Tuple` (or possibly something else) from properties in your entity and let EF handle the rest.

The problem is, the only way you could treat the result of such method in a strongly-typed way would be if you knew the exact type it should return at compile-type, which it seems you don't.

The best you can do is to treat the result as a non-generic `IEnumerable` or alternatively try to use `dynamic`.

Comment: I could create something like the folow: IEnumerable<T>DoSelect(string[] field) where T : class { ... return Expression.Lambda..etc. I preferably don't want using dynamic types. Can you show me some example? I'm not expert with Expression class..

Comment: @bit, how do you want to use it? If you want to specify both the return type and the fields, it means you know what fields you want to select and there is no need for the string parameters. Or do you want to fill just some fields of the type?

Comment: ok, this is my issue: I must retrieving any entities by applying some projecton related at to declared columns in my grid, so I cannot use classic Select lambda. All what I know are properties to select in string format (column name), so, the caller will execute something like this: obj = Retrieve<Customers>(new string[] {"id", "name"}); .... and my retrieve method could be appear like follow: IQueryable<T> Retrieve<T>(string[] fileds) where T : class.. Notice thah obj is already an IQeryable<Customers Or Other> object. have you realize me?

Comment: @bit,why not just select all the properties? That seems like the easiest way.

Comment: No, I can't because many db's tables contains too much field and some of them are stream data field so my application wiil be destinated to fails about optimization and quickness...